# Как перенести скрипт из файла html в js

Tags: jquery

Имеется вот такой скрипт.

```js
<script>
var carousels = document.querySelectorAll('#carousels .carousel');
var currentCarousel = 0;
var carouselInterval = setInterval(nextCarousel,5000); /* Интервал между картинками */

function nextCarousel(){
carousels[currentCarousel].className = 'carousel';
currentCarousel = (currentCarousel+1)%carousels.length;
carousels[currentCarousel].className = 'carousel demonstration';
}
</script>
```

Как правильно подключить скрипт `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` с `html` страницы?

Comment: Как вам тег `<script>`?

Comment: Взять и перенести. Вырезать отсюда и вставить туда в конец. Вопрос в том - зачем, если у Вас код свой, а то цельная библиотека, в которую лезь не нужно?

Comment: Нужно, правил библиотеку, но опыта мало.
Не хочется засорять код скриптами. Есть библиотека где я ранее добавлял слайдер, но с этим морока. 
Переменные где то теряю. 
Вставляю по типу $(function() { ... });

Comment: @ДенисНескажев, так не нужно править библиотеки без сильной необходимости. Просто создайте отдельный файл, перенесите код туда и подключите этот файл: `<script src="mycode.js"></script>`

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar спасибо, так и сделаю.